# Cannot get comment of other people from Instagram API

Tags: laravel-5, instagram, instagram-api

I use Instagram API to get all comments include text comment and someone's comment, but I only get my comment. I use

> https://api.instagram.com/v1/media/{media-id}/comments?access_token=ACCESS-TOKEN

Any solution?

Comment: are u in sandbox mode, if so u will only see yours until you go live

Answer (score 2):

It seems your app is in Sandbox. In sandbox mode you get your own data and other sandbox invited users data but can't get any public user data.

To get other users data you must submit your app with valid case. If they approve your app then you can use your app to get any public user data.